# Running multiple tests on Promise results - Mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, promise, mocha.js, chai

I want run a bunch of tests on the results obtained from a promise call. I know it can be done as:

```
it ('should pass test foo1', () => {
  return promisecall()
    .then(result => {
      expect(result.length).to.equal(42)
      expect(some other test on data)
      expect(some other test on data)
                .
                .
    })
})
```

According to my understanding, what this does is:
Runs a single test (i.e should pass test foo1) which passes only if all the expect conditions are true, and these expect parts will not show in the output screen.

How can I add multiple 'it' / unit tests on the results of a single promise result, so that the different test cases actually show up in the output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to group them together in a `describe()` and run the promise in a `before()`:

```
describe('things with promises', () => {
    var promiseResult;

    before(() => promiseCall().then(result => promiseResult = result));

    it ('should pass test foo1', () => expect(promiseResult.length).to.equal(42));

    it ('should pass test foo2', () => expect(some other test));

    // ...
});
```